# Creating an internal clock within Coldfusion .cfc file to execute scheduled tasks

Tags: time, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am needing to do scheduled tasks based off an ever going internal clock. I know this is possible with Javascript, but this solution will need to be hosted within a Application.cfc file. I tried to just use a "Now" function within a OnRequestStart function, however the problem is if I need to let's say send an email at midnight to someone, but no one makes a request at midnight, then the email won't send. I tried to do the same function as well in the OnApplicationStart function, but that will only run once ideally. I was thinking about using the CreateTime method within the OnApplicationStart function, but how would I increment the time in real time, if that makes sense. I hope this is more clear on what is actually needed. Here is some code I tried out, however I am not really sure how to test if this works honestly.

```
<cffunction NAME="internalclock">
   <cfset today = #day(Now())#>
   <cfset  h = #hour(Now())#>
   <cfset  m = #minute(Now())#>
   <cfset  s = #second(Now())#>
   <cfset  m = #checktime(m)#>
   <cfset  s = #checktime(s)#>
   <cfsetting requestTimeOut = ".5">
</cffunction>
<cffunction  NAME="checktime">
   <cfif i LESS THAN 10 > i="0"+i
   <cfreturn i>
   </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Edit:
 I'm having some issues accessing a variable within a page2.cfc file. The way the data is flowing is that I initialize the variable in an Application.cfc file, rewrite the same variable in page2.cfc, and access the modified variable in page3.cfm. Page3.cfm is just a test to ensure that the variable is in fact defined and updating as expected. I should mention that page2.cfc has a scheduled task on it and runs around every minute. Here is some example code:

```
Application.cfc
<CFFUNCTION NAME="OnApplicationStart">
  <cfset Application.currenttime = 0>
</CFFUNCTION>

page2.cfc
<CFFUNCTION NAME ="Counter">
  <cfset Application.currenttime = #Now()#>
</CFFUNCTION>

page3.cfm
<cfoutput>
  #Application.currenttime#
</cfoutput>
```

The error I am getting is that either the current time variable is displaying as 0, or if I change the output to `Counter.currenttime` it says it's not defined. I am sure I am doing something dumb, but I would appreciate the help.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What are you ultimately using this internal clock for? If you're wanting to do something at a specific time or on a specific schedule, you can just schedule a task in the CFAdmin.

Comment: @Shawn you're the best man. It's in relation to the previous post, that's actually the route I'm going now. Just setting it up. Originally I didn't know the scheduled tasks were a thing, but thank you!

Comment: @Shawn have you ever tried to get a variable from your Application.cfc, pass that onto another .cfc file, mutate that variable's data, run the scheduled task on this file, and try to pass the variable over to be displayed in a .cfm file before? The variable is in application scope, but for some reason I can't seem to parse the variable from the second file to the third. I can share my code if needed

Comment: If you are still following the same workflow you described earlier, I don't think you're specifically passing the application variable to your 2nd page, nor is there really a "hand off" from pg2 to pg3. Scheduled tasks are essentially an HTTP call to the page, so the `application` scope should be available to it where you'll change your `application` variable. It's kind of "included" in that Scheduled Task file. Then just call `application.changedVariable` in pg3. If you aren't able to see it in your 3rd page, make sure that it is actually using `Application.cfc`. How is page3 being called?

Comment: And if this is still to see how many times an API is being called and then report it, this may be an awful lot of work. Does your application and your API use a database? If so, it'll be much easier and much more persistent to store and increment a value there from your API and reference it from your application or a scheduled reporting task.

Comment: And RE: your code above >> `i` is not defined in your second function,  `checktime()`. It looks like you're trying to pass in an integer of either minutes or seconds of `Now()` and then converting it to a string with a `0` in front. Are you trying to pad those values out to 2 characters and then make that a string?  You also don't need the `#` symbols, unless you are using the variable name inside a quoted string. And if you scope the variables you use in the functions, they won't leak out. And last, if you are familiar with Javascript, you might find `cfscript` syntax much easier to use.

Comment: https://cfdocs.org/script

Comment: @Shawn I agree, there's probably a much easier way to do this, but these are the requirements I must meet. I don't want to have a database for this, because frankly I don't need to store this data, this is just like internal analytics and a sort of security measure. That being said, essentially the way the data flow will work is that I will initialize a variable in OnApplicationStart, access that application variable in a different cfc file (because I can't run a scheduled task on application.cfc), rewrite that variable with the Now() method that's updated every minute via the schedule task

Comment: However, I am currently running into the issue of accessing the variable within page2.cfc in page3.cfm for some reason and I am not sure why

Comment: You don't have to have a database just for this. I was just saying if you already had a database, it's much easier to use that database to track the variables you need.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, the coldfusion community truly is the greatest

Comment: Are both pages using the same Application.cfc? Are you calling the function `counter()` when you run the scheduled task? If you aren't doing anything else in the function, you can just use `<cfset application.currenttime = now()>`.

Comment: @Shawn right. I am calling the function Counter, and both are using the same application.cfc. Thank you for that. When I access the modified variable from page2, in page3.cfm, would I access it using `Application.counter.currenttime`?

Comment: If your variable is `application.currenttime` that would be what you use to access it.

Comment: Are you doing anything in `counter()` other than setting that application variable? Or really anything more complex than can or should simply be done in the single page itself? You could always just try setting the variable on a clean page without using a function and see if it's updating your application variable correctly. It sounds like either `application.currenttime` isn't being set with the Scheduled Task, or the application is restarting when you call `page3.cfm` and setting `application.currenttime` back to 0.

Comment: You could add `application.appStartTime=now()` to `onApplicationStart()` and outputl `#application.appStartTime#`in `page3.cfm`, and see if it's getting reset each time you call the page. Of course, if you don't restart the application, I think it should fail, which would essentially be another positive test.

Comment: @shawn thank you for your help. It turns out, I have been over thinking this like crazy. All you have to do is create a variable for time and a variable for counting in the onappstart, increment the counting variable per request, reset the counter per hour or whatever you want and update the variable from onappstart with the last request time. Super simple

Comment: Just a tip about cffunctions. *Always* `var` all function local variables. Otherwise you can unintentionally create some bizarre bugs due to threading issues. Especially if the parent component's stored in a shared scope.

Comment: @Ageax I will definitely keep that in mind because that is definitely the case. Already applied most of your lessons haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be done via Scheduled Tasks within Coldfusion Administrator. I didn't know that was a thing before actually making this post. My apologies.

Thank you,